# python3 zip reads gzipped text file as bytes string but python2 izip read as normal string

Tags: python-3.x, gzip

Again, I am in the process of translating python2 code to python3. I ran into trouble when I replace itertools.izip with zip. Here is an example:

I have two gzipped text files:
data1.txt.gz
with content

```
a
b
```

and data2.txt.gz

```
e
f
```

python2 izip version

```
from itertools import izip
import sys
import gzip

def read(file):
  fh = gzip.open(file,"rb")
  with fh as f:
    while True:
      l1 = f.readline()
      if not l1:
        break
      l2 = f.readline()
      yield [l1, l2]

for a,b in izip(read("data1.txt.gz"),read("data2.txt.gz")):
  sys.stdout.write("%s\n%s\n" % (a,b))
```

This shows an output of

```
['a\n', 'b\n']
['e\n', 'f\n']
```

However, for the python3 zip version:

```
import sys
import gzip

def read(file):
  fh = gzip.open(file,"rb")
  with fh as f:
    while True:
      l1 = f.readline()
      if not l1:
        break
      l2 = f.readline()
      yield [l1, l2]

for a,b in zip(read("data1.txt.gz"),read("data2.txt.gz")):
  sys.stdout.write("%s\n%s\n" % (a,b))
```

The output becomes:

```
[b'a\n', b'b\n']
[b'e\n', b'f\n']
```

Why's that?

This causes my program to crash
after that. To fix this, I can add

```
a = list(map(bytes.decode,a))
b = list(map(bytes.decode,b))
```

after right after the for statement.
Presumably, this is not looking good potentially slower as well
But is there a better looking and faster way to do this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what happens if you do not open it in binary more? Instead use text mode by open('rt')

Comment: If the input is a plain text. python3 zip doesn't make them byte strings. So probably itertools.izip did the conversion by default?

Comment: Try opening in text mode. See answer for behavior.

Comment: It's just a change in terminology.  Python 2 `str` type is exactly the same as Python 3's `bytes` type.  Python 2 was a lot more lax in letting you mix `str` and `unicode` so it was probably applying automatic conversions you weren't even aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system with python3:

```
>>> import gzip
>>> sample_zip_file = 'x1.txt.gz'
>>> 
>>> fh_textmode = gzip.open(sample_zip_file, 'rt')
>>> fh_binarymode = gzip.open(sample_zip_file, 'rb')
>>> 
>>> data_textmode = fh_textmode.read()
>>> data_binarymode = fh_binarymode.read()
>>> 
>>> type(data_textmode)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(data_binarymode)
<class 'bytes'>
>>>
```

Comment: If we are sure the gzipped file is a text file, then open it as rt probably is a cleaner way that works for both python2 and python3.